# C3 bar chart unknown number of bars

Tags: javascript, arrays, c3.js

I am using C3.js to create a bar chart.

My case is as such:

I want to collect an `X` number of data and display them in my chart for this i have created the following script:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/AcademyStat/academy_module_user_report',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        request: 'ajax',
        team_id: team_id,
        module_id: module_id
    },
    success: function (data)
    {
        if(data != null)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                var add_data = [data[i]['name'], data[i]['score']]
                char_data.push(add_data);
            }
            var chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: '#score_chart',
                data: {
                    columns: [
                        char_data

                    ],
                    type: 'bar'
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see from the above example i am looping through the data and then adding it to an array untill i have an array of array's (unknown number of data).

However when i run this in my browser i get the following error in the `console`:

```
    Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 286.6,NaN L286.6,NaN L531.4,NaN L531.4,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 1102.6,NaN L1102.6,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 286.6,NaN L286.6,NaN L531.4,NaN L531.4,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 1102.6,NaN L1102.6,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 286.6,NaN L286.6,NaN L531.4,NaN L531.4,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 1102.6,NaN L1102.6,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 286.6,NaN L286.6,NaN L531.4,NaN L531.4,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 1102.6,NaN L1102.6,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 286.6,NaN L286.6,NaN L531.4,NaN L531.4,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 1102.6,NaN L1102.6,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 286.6,NaN L286.6,NaN L531.4,NaN L531.4,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 1102.6,NaN L1102.6,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 286.6,NaN L286.6,NaN L531.4,NaN L531.4,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 1102.6,NaN L1102.6,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 286.6,NaN L286.6,NaN L531.4,NaN L531.4,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 1102.6,NaN L1102.6,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 286.6,NaN L286.6,NaN L531.4,NaN L531.4,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 1102.6,NaN L1102.6,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 286.6,NaN L286.6,NaN L531.4,NaN L531.4,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 1102.6,NaN L1102.6,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 286.6,NaN L286.6,NaN L531.4,NaN L531.4,NaN z" d3.min.js:5
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="M 1102.6,NaN L1102.6,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN L1347.3999999999999,NaN z
```

However if i instead use the method `pop` the data is displayed fine. The only problem with `pop();` is that i would have to know how many arrays my `char_data` array has and that is impossible for me to know.

Has anyone tried something similar or know how i might fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are setting the charts `columns` to an array inside an array `columns: [ [ ['name', 'score'] ] ]`

Change the `columns: [ char_data ]` to `columns: char_data`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/AcademyStat/academy_module_user_report',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        request: 'ajax',
        team_id: team_id,
        module_id: module_id
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var add_data = [data[i]['name'], data[i]['score']]
                char_data.push(add_data);
            }
            var chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: '#score_chart',
                data: {
                    columns: char_data,
                    type: 'bar'
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```